# Setting a dynamic pivot as a print area

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I have tried via a named range however for some reason the equation keeps changing automatically within the named range after I run the a macro. So I attempted to set the range within the macro itself.
I am writing a macro that will look through a slicer and save the 2 sheets as a PDF. The 2nd tab has pivot which area range will change each time a slicer changes. Can someone help me so that this will print to PDF dynamically?

```
Sub Loopexport()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable

'Hide non-printable sheets
    Sheets("Overview").Visible = False
    Sheets("KPExport").Visible = False

Set ws2 = Sheets("Id CUps")

Set PT = ws2.PivotTables(1)

'Set print areas
    Sheets("Stats").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$M$39"
    ws2.PageSetup.PrintArea = PT.TableRange2 'this is where I am receiving the type mismatch. and the = "My named range" kept changing automatically at the end.

    With Sheets("Id CUps").Columns("D:D")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
    End With

'Print Regions
'Export N1
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Dt").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array("[UserID].[Dept].&[N1]")

ChDir ("C:\My Docs\A\B\Export")
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\My Docs\A\B\Export\N1 - " & Format(Now(), "YYYY") & "M" & Format(Now(), "MM")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ws2.PageSetup.PrintArea = PT.TableRange2.Address
```